# How to set a starting viewcontroller.xib in iOS using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xib, appdelegate

I am new to iOS. I create a single view application. Its have one view controller. When compile the application its show the fully black colour of my view controller. Now what I need is how to initialise my view controller as first view controller as well as I need to initialise navigation controller of my app. Note: I created xib view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
HomeViewController *homeVc = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeVc];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Open ViewController.xib. Select the File's Owner placeholder. Open the Identity Inspector and change the class to ViewController.

[image]

Open the Connections Inspector and connect the view outlet.

[image]

Update AppDelegate.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```